# Scrolling to and Highlighting Anchor With Class of ".agree" After Results Are Loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to scroll to the anchor `.agree` that is displayed at the end of the questionairee.  The first question determines what is displayed at the end which is why at the end of the document there are `#if_one` `#if_two` and `#if_three`.. so the solution would have to work with all 3 possible answers.  I'm trying to get it to scroll to the div (not jump) at the end and also highlight the div so the border becomes red.

Here is the section with the anchors I'm trying to scroll to and highlight:

```
<div id="if_one">
    <a href="http://websitelinkhere.com/1" class="button_primary agree">If Question 1 = Answer 1</a>
</div>
<div id="if_two">
    <a href="http://websitelinkhere.com/2" class="button_primary agree">If Question 1 = Answer 2</a>
</div>
<div id="if_three">
    <a href="http://websitelinkhere.com/3" class="button_primary agree">If Question 1 = Answer 3</a>
</div>
```

And here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TwtD9/)

Comment: :target for styling the 'targeted' element  +  jquery-scrollTo  to smoothly scroll your page ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animating the page is the easy part, you just need to do this:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: target.offset().top
}, 200);
```

This will animate the scroll of `html` and `body` to the top-edge of `target`.  No need for using plugins or extensions on this occasion.

The complex part, however, is identifying which of your three available answers is the one you want to scroll to.  Without a bit more of your code, I'm not sure we can be of more help to you on that one.

Just to extend upon my example above a little more, if the answer you wanted to scroll to was #2:

```
// assign the correct target
var target = $('#if_two');

// scroll!
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: target.offset().top
}, 200);
```

You can speed up or slow down the effect by changing `200` in the above examples.

You can also change the style of your targetted element in the animation callback, so in-all it would look something like:

```
// assign the correct target
var target = $('#if_two');

// scroll!
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: target.offset().top
}, 200, function(){
    target.css({'border-color': 'red'})
});
```

Comment: I guess I can wrap the 3 answers in another div and target that, but I added the javascript code to the top of the JSFiddle and it stopped working.. here is what i have: http://jsfiddle.net/TwtD9/1/